# некорректная работа, выводит белый экран, а должен список

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hibernate

Подскажите выводит белый экран а должен список

```
   public void takeAndInsert(){

    Session session =  HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    Transaction trans = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/users/tima/desktop/words.txt")));
        String line = null;
        StopWordsDict st = null;
        trans = session.beginTransaction();
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            List<StopWordsDict> result = session.createQuery("from StopWordsDict where word = :word").setParameter("word",line).list();
            if(result == null || result.size() == 0){
                st = new StopWordsDict();
                st.setWord(line);
                session.save(st);
            }else {
                continue;
            }
        }

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

что-то не то выводит белый экран

Comment: В приведённом коде нет ни одной строчки связанной с выводом чего-либо куда-либо, кроме вывода в консоль ошибок в блоках `catch`.

Comment: Класс с методом main() выложи

Answer (score 0):

Хехе во код:) Вывод где? И вопервых

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            List<StopWordsDict> result = session.createQuery("from StopWordsDict where word = :word").setParameter("word",line).list();
            if(result == null || result.size() == 0){
                st = new StopWordsDict();
                st.setWord(line);
                session.save(st);
                //МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ ЗДЕСЯ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ВЫВОД, А ВЫ КАК ДУМАЕТЕ?
            }else {
                continue;
                //СМУТНОЕ СОМНЕНИЕ, А ЗАЧЕМ ВАЩЕ CONTINUE ЕСЛИ И ТАК КОНЕЦ ЦИКЛА
            }
        }
```

Расскажите идею скрипта, вижу работа с файлом, но что он делает не знаю, вижу чтение по строковое и странное дейсвие с ними. Если вы расскажите идею дополю(хаха, смешная опечатка) пост решениями из стандартной джавы.